# Short way to write an event?

Tags: c#, events

Typically we use this code:

```
    private EventHandler _updateErrorIcons;
    public event EventHandler UpdateErrorIcons
    {
        add { _updateErrorIcons += value; }
        remove { _updateErrorIcons -= value; }
    }
```

Is there a similar shortcut like with automatic properties?
Something like:

```
   public event EventHandler UpdateErrorIcons { add; remove; }
```

Comment: that is really funny, most people never even heard about extended code :)

Comment: yeah, even though I've seen people do this, I never personally use this, the compiler adds it later.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yep. Get rid of the `{ add; remove; }` part and the backing delegate field and you're golden:

```
public event EventHandler UpdateErrorIcons;
```

That's it!

Let me just add that before you asked this question, I hadn't even thought about the fact that the auto-implemented version of events is inconsistent with that of properties. Personally, I would actually *prefer* it if auto-implemented events worked the way you first attempted in your question. It would be more consistent, and it would also serve as a mental reminder that events are *not* identical to delegate fields, just like properties are not identical to regular fields.

Honestly, I think you're the rare exception where you actually knew about the custom syntax *first*. A lot of .NET developers have no clue there's an option to implement your own `add` and `remove` methods at all.

---

**Update**: Just for your own peace of mind, I have confirmed using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) that the default implementation of events in C# 4 (i.e., the implementation that gets generated when you go the auto-implemented route) is equivalent to this:

```
private EventHandler _updateErrorIcons;
public event EventHandler UpdateErrorIcons
{
    add
    {
        EventHandler current, original;
        do
        {
            original = _updateErrorIcons;
            EventHandler updated = (EventHandler)Delegate.Combine(original, value);
            current = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _updateErrorIcons, updated, original);
        }
        while (current != original);
    }
    remove
    {
        // Same deal, only with Delegate.Remove instead of Delegate.Combine.
    }
}
```

Note that the above utilizes lock-free synchronization to effectively serialize `add` and `remove` calls. So if you're using the latest C# compiler, you don't need to implement `add`/`remove` yourself *even* for synchronization.

Comment: And the backing field. (In fact, OP, you'll find a lot of people are not even aware of the `add` and `remove` event accessors.)

Comment: We're using the add & remove in some events for synchronization.

Comment: @Carra: Depending on which version of the C# compiler you're using, you may not have to worry about that: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2010/03/05/events-get-a-little-overhaul-in-c-4-part-i-locks.aspx

Comment: Great to know. I remember reading the best practices for event - thread safety when we were still on the 2.0 framework.

Answer (score 5):

```
public event EventHandler UpdateErrorIcons;
```

is just fine

you can use

```
yourObbject.UpdateErrorIcons += YourFunction;
```

Answer (score 2):

`add {}` and `remove {}` are used only in special cases where you need to handle event hookups manually. Us mere mortals normally just use `public event EventHandler UpdateErrorIcons;` where "EventHandler" is the delegate of choice.

For instance:

```
public delegate void MyEventDelegate(object sender, string param1);
public event MyEventDelegate MyEvent;
```

Note that because MyEvent is null if it doesn't have any listeners you need to check if it is null before invoking it. A standard method for doing this check is:

```
public void InvokeMyEvent(string param1)
{
    MyEventDelegate myEventDelegate = MyEvent;
    if (myEventDelegate != null)
        myEventDelegate(this, param1);
}
```

A key element in this check is to make a copy of the object in question first and then work only on the copy. If not you could get a rare race condition where another thread unhooks between your if and your call.

Comment: Yes, we'd typically use it to add synchronization later.

Comment: @Carra: Unless I'm mistaken, the default implementation of `add` and `remove` in the latest versions of the .NET framework actually does include synchronization.